# EventHandler saying method not found in Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, eventhandler

I've been having some issues getting the Xamarin Live Player to work. I've synced the app with my Visual Studio Project, but when I try to run it the program throws an error saying that one of my methods is not found within the solution. However, the method is there and does not seem to be missing anything to my knowledge.

[snippet of my error message from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nGnu.jpg)

Here is my code:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public async void onMyAppointmentsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewAppointments());
        }

        public async void onNewAppointmentClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewAppointment());
        }

        public async void onContactUsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactSalon());
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have tried deleting the bin and obj folders, as well as cleaning and rebuilding my solution to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Deploy/debug your app directly against the emulator/simulator and/or device (without using Live), if it works, then post an issue on http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com